# Angular: ngIf behaviour with Img element while using setInterval

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ng-if

I have this image element

```
<img *ngIf="indicator" src="assets/on.gif" width="20px" height="20px">
```

Now, while declaring

```
indicator:boolean = false;
```

So by default I don't have the image

Now I have a button, if click on it, it will call a setInterval method

```
setInterval(this.setIndicator, 2000);

 setIndicator() {
    this.indicator = true;
    console.log(this.indicator);
  }
```

In console, I can see the value of this element as true, but it is not showing the img

If I set it true manually, it is reflecting that img. i.e

```
<img *ngIf="true" src="assets/on.gif" width="20px" height="20px">
```

Comment: use {} and print the value of indicator at the end of img tag...check whether you get true/false

Comment: it remains false, not changing to true, as two way binding it should change to true

Comment: Does it work if you change it to this:  `setInterval(()=>this.setIndicator(), 2000);`?

Comment: @John I don't know if you know about it, but you are a gem , it is working, but what happen behind the scene, what difference it is making

Comment: I created an answer with some more background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use

```
setInterval(()=>this.setIndicator(), 2000);
```

Using an arrow function (`()=>`), you are binding the scope of `this` to the Componenent, and not the scope inside the setInterval.

`this.indicator` inside the setInterval is not the same as your component's `indicator`. Using the arrow function solves this.

[This article](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc) can be helpful for more details

Answer (score -1):

I defined code in html as following

```
 <img *ngIf="indicator" src="assests/image.jpg" width="100vw" height="100vh">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setIndicator()">Click</button>
```

then in component.ts, I create indicator property

```
indicator:boolean = false
```

and create setIndicator() method

```
setIndicator(){
  setTimeout(() =>{
     this.indicator=true;
  },2000);
```

code worked this way